# Build Failed in Visual Studio React Native App

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm getting the following error in VS, can anyone please provide a fix for it, what I'm doing wrong? Is there something missing?

```
C:\Users\Glock\Desktop\Project\Instagram-clone-master\android>gradlew assembleRelease
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, undefined, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, undefined, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Glock\Desktop\Project\Instagram-clone-master\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 170

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Glock\Desktop\Project\Instagram-clone-master\android\undefined'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

I created a new project, and it works fine with BUILD SUCCESSFUL. But for my existing project, now I have this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Glock\Desktop\Project\Instagram-clone-master\android\undefined'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}
```

Comment: Can you run npm install in your root directory and try it again?

Comment: Yes I did, please check update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run this command in the root folder of your project

> npm install --save-dev @react-native-community/cli

Then run your project through this command

> yarn|npm react-native run-ios

- **Remove any global installation of react-native**

Comment: On the second command, it says: 
'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Weseem then you don't have `yarn` installed ... I meant by `npm|yarn` is to use either yarn or npm

Comment: I just did: npm install yarn -g

Comment: Now i have this error: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Is that error appear on every react-native project you create (I mean try to create a brand new project and see if it has this issue) ... create new project using `npx react-native init newProject`

Comment: @Waseem I'd suggest you remove you node-modules folder and reinstall it along with trying to apply the fix in my answer ... if it didn't work --> I highly recommend you create a brand new react-native project and migrate your code to it